# Выборка из 2 таблиц БД

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Вопрос глупый, но все же никак не разберусь...

Есть 2 запроса из БД:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE id = '$_GET[id]'");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE user_id = '$_GET[id]'");
```

Как их объединить в один запрос?

Я так понимаю, должны быть поля пересекающиеся, например, id в одной базе должен быть равен id в другой?
Хочу понять, как делать выборку данных из 2 таблиц, чтобы не хранить все данные, нужные в одной таблице.

Comment: У вас как-то все в одной таблице 'table' лежит.
Для объединения результатов выборок используют JOIN.

Comment: @Get ответил на ваш вопрос. Чтобы получить более развернутый ответ, поставьте конкретнее вопрос. К тому же обратите внимание на замечание @maxspb89.

Comment: Да, да. Ошибся. Исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
SELECT
  table1.id as 'id_t1',
  table1.name as 'name_t1',

  table2.user_id as 'id_t2',
  table2.name as 'name_t2'

FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id = '$_GET[id]' AND table2.user_id = '$_GET[id]';
```

Но уверен, что это не решение проблемы, т.к. почему-то кажется, что вопрос еще изменится в пользу перекрестных выборок. ;)

Ну а пока держите http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3f38/1

Comment: На первый взгляд то, что нужно. Просто есть данные пользователей, и не все они хранятся в одной таблице. Вот чтобы можно было дернуть эти данные, основываясь, например, на id пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = xx AND user_id = yy;"
```

Comment: Я исправил вопрос, у меня данные в 2 разных таблицах.